# How to use dependency injection in quartz.net scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm trying to run up quartz.net service in asp.net mvc 4 application where we are using dependency injection & services. In this application I need quartz for sending emails with daily period. But whats the strange I can't use DI in quartz.net code because it's broke if I'm add constructor to it. Is anybody have any ideas how I can resolve that problem?

```
namespace BBWT.Web.Scheduler {
    public class EmailJob : IJob {
        //private readonly IEmailSender emailSender;

        //public EmailJob(IEmailSender emailSender) {
        //    this.emailSender = emailSender;
        //}

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
            var result = new List<DebtorsDTO>()
            {
                new DebtorsDTO()
                {
                    InvoiceId = 1,
                    ClientName = "Some Client",
                    ClientEmail = "someemail@mail.com",
                    ClientId = 1,
                    //SessionId = 1,
                    Date = "17.07.2015",
                    TutorName = "Tutor Tutor",
                    InvoiceName = "Invoice Name 1",
                    AgedAnalysis = "some analysis",
                    SevedDaysOverdue = 1000,
                    FourteenDaysOverdue = 0,
                    TwentyOneDaysOverdue = 0,
                    MoreThatTwentyEightDaysOverdue = 0,
                    Status = "Sent 7 day reminder",
                    IsSelectForEmail = false,
                    OnChase = true,
                    OnHold = false
                }
            };

            //string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\Test\Test.txt", lines);

        }
    }

    public class JobScheduler {
        public static void Start() {
            // Get an instance of the Quartz.Net scheduler
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            // Start the scheduler if its in standby
            if(!scheduler.IsStarted)
                scheduler.Start();

            // Define the Job to be scheduled
            var job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("JobMonthSchedulerSeventhDay", "IT")
                .RequestRecovery()
                .Build();

            // Associate a trigger with the Job
            var trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("TriggerMonthSchedulerSeventhDay", "IT")
                //.WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 7 1/1 ? *") // visit http://www.cronmaker.com/ Queues the job every minute
                .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
                .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                .WithPriority(1)
                .Build();

            // Validate that the job doesn't already exists
            if(scheduler.CheckExists(new JobKey("JobMonthSchedulerSeventhDay", "IT"))) {
                scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey("JobMonthSchedulerSeventhDay", "IT"));
            }

            var schedule = scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }

    public class EmailSenderFormDTO {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string EmailTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/integrate-quartznet-with-your-favourite.html might offer some insight

Comment: I also done a write-up about quartz, but with Autofac: http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/07/quartz-net-in-azure-with-autofac-smoothness/ - A lot of good info is in comments, so read them as well.

Comment: thank you guys, will take a look. That quartz.net make me crazy

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861146/create-a-quartz-net-job-with-several-constructor-parameters/31892357#31892357

Answer (score 5):

I wrote up a short blog post accompanied by a YouTube video and source code on GitHub showing how to accomplish this. It takes you step by step through how to add dependency injection for your jobs, and explains how it all works. The example uses Ninject as the IoC library, but it should be pretty trivial with structure of the code I put together to switch that out for something else (e.g. Autofac).

Blog Post with video and source code: http://knightcodes.com/.net/2016/08/15/dependency-injection-for-quartz-net.html

Comment: Both blog post and GitHub source code are removed. That's why you should always copy the code to SO, making your answer complete and self contained. Links should be used as reference or aditional resouces, not as the answer itself :)

Comment: thanks, but still no on SO, so if the blog is moved again, the link will fail again