# Create a Quartz.NET Job with several constructor parameters

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a job which needs to kick off some methods on another object. I'd like to be able to pass these into the job in its constructor.

Looking around, it seems that the only way to achieve this is to use one of IoC frameworks. Whilst this method will be a solution for me in the future, right now I need a vanilla solution, not requiring any IoC.

I am aware of the `JobDataMap` but the [Best Practices](https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/best-practices) documentation advises against this due to serialization. The object is multi-threaded and statefull, so serializing would be code suicide anyhow.

How can I create a job similar to below:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

        public StopMonitoring(IFoo foo)
        {
            _foo = foo;
        }

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            foo.GetCurrentState();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you do not want to use an IoC framework? Just asking because I recently implemented dependency injection for jobs using Ninject and would be happy to share what I came up with. What I did was make my own job factory that inherits from SimpleJobFactory and added my DI bits in there.

Comment: I will be adding IoC, but it's a shared project.  To be honest, it's bugging me that I couldn't see a way to do it that wasn't IoC.  I've figured it out now though, I was overcomplicating it.  I couldn't see a tidy way of doing it without it.  Fact was, there wasn't one.

Comment: I'm confused by the code in this question. Is the StopMonitoring method actually supposed to be the constructor, in which case it should be called MyJob?   Are you asking how to ensure when MyJob is constructed it is given a "foo" through the constructor?

Answer (score 22):

You need to use JobFactory:

```
internal sealed class IntegrationJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public IntegrationJobFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;

        var job = (IJob)_container.Resolve(jobDetail.JobType);
        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
var _scheduler.JobFactory = new IntegrationJobFactory(container);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer.  Can't believe out of all the complex solutions, the simple one is the one that worked.  Used this to get it working with autofac.  this should be marked as the answer

Comment: @josh glad to help :)

Comment: @Backs if i have several IJob that have constructor parameters so can i create several jobfacroty for one scheduler? not that i am using windows service for quartz.net

Comment: I'm confused by this answer - it doesn't seem to relate to the code in the question?  Where in the answer is foo passed to the constructor and\or does _foo get set??

Comment: @mutex that's how IoC-containers work. Register `MyJob` in container, and container will resolve/create it.

Comment: I understand how IoC containers work, it just didn't seem to relate to the code in the question at all.  Though TBH the question code looks quite confused too... the constructor seems to be "StopMonitoring" but the class called "MyJob"?

Comment: @mutex Good spot.  It's so long ago that I can't remember.

Comment: @BanksySan - all good, I just happened to be looking for how to do something similar with Quartz and there weren't that many question\answers that matched.   I ended up solving my problem a different way but I suspect you could edit your answer to cast as type MyJob and if it is a MyJob set a Foo property in the NewJob method? That would avoid the need for IoC as per question, but would also probably require edits on the Question to make sense though, and I'm not 100% sure it would work as haven't tried it.