# IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create in same instance. Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net

If I will not create empty constructor my Execute will not work.

My Code

```html
 public class CalculateManager : ICalculateManager, IJob
    {
        static IStrongDataRepository _strongDataRepository;
        private readonly ICalculateProtocolOne  _calculateOne;
        private Dictionary<string, CalculateModel> _resultDictionary;
 
 public CalculateManager(IStrongDataRepository strongDataRepository,
            ICalculateOne calculateOne)
        {
            _calculateOne = calculateOne;
            _resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CalculateModel>();

            this.Start();
        }
        
        
       
        
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here");
            var x = _resultDictionary;
        }
        
        public CalculateManager()
        {

        }
        
        
        public async void Start()
        {
            TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(16, 36, 0);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today.Add(startTime);

            IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CalculateManager>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .StartAt(now)
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInMinutes(2)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
```

If I will not create empty constructor. My quarz build will not work. But in this way I have two different instance. In this `var x = _resultDictionary;` I have null. But in real when it create with all necessary interfaces in first instance thre are in _resultDictionary a lot off results from calculate. How I need to create `IJobDetail job` that it use the same instance.

Comment: Clarification is needed about what it is that is ***actually*** trying to be done. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what is the problem and what is being asked.

Comment: the broblem is in different instance of CalculateManager.  But it must work with one instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Quartz.NET Job with several constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861146/create-a-quartz-net-job-with-several-constructor-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a static variable in class 
`static List<CalculateManager> _instanceList = new List<CalculateManager>()`;

And put to this list all instance. When Quartz.NET start Execute. It is starting Execute on instace where constcutor without param. And I fine my Instatce such way.

`var instance = _instanceList[0];`